Tough Orange Rind in Marmalade
I have a 3-fruit marmalade recipe  I've been using for years, and recently, there have been occasions where the orange-rind, in particular, has been very tough, despite being finely shredded.
The process involves pressure-cooking orange, grapefruit and lemon together with some of the water, before shredding, completing the syrup, and cooking out to the gelling-point. When shredding, the peel seems to be OK.
Is this the selection of oranges? is there a way of telling which fruit will toughen?
Or, is there another mistake I can avoid?

That is very curious that you are following the same recipe and are now getting different results.
The best tip I gotten for avoiding tough marmalade rind is to cook and soften the peel before adding any sugar or sweetener. You didn't specify when you add the sweetener (or even if you add any), but that is one factor that can impact toughness. I found this article from the BBC states that "once sugar is added the peel won't soften further, so the best way to make sure it softens is to cook the oranges on their own first."
Another thing I note from many of the recipes I have tried (also unclear if you do this already) is that they usually suggest soaking the oranges over night, which seems to have a dual-purpose of helping to release pectin (to make the marmalade more "gel" like) and can also help soften the rind.
Lastly, I have had my fair share of overcooking marmalade to the point where it ended up more like candy than jam, so paying attention to cooking times is likely also a factor.
If you are following the recipe exactly and none of the above are causes, experimenting with different orange varieties could definitely help narrow down to a reasonable explanation. For example, Seville oranges are considered by many to be * the best * due to having the ideal ratio of peel and white pith making them rich in pectin.

Thanks @emmabee! I do pressure-cook without sugar. The two suggestions that may well earn you your tick, absent a startling definitive answer very soon: 1, soaking.. I'll try that, maybe after scrubbing in hot water to eliminate any wax that may be there, 2: aiming for a slacker gel, which I prefer anyway. (3-fruit gives me a great, heady, citrus-oil perfume without Seville, which are hard to buy, here)
